# live audio streaming server based on gstreamer and a client with vlc playing the incoming stream

Tags: gstreamer

I need to set up a live audio streaming server with gstreamer. Server should be sending live audio to client and at the client side, vlc player should be used to play the incoming stream. I am using the following code

```
VIDEO_CAPS="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264"

gst-launch -v udpsrc caps=$VIDEO_CAPS port=4444 \
          ! gstrtpbin .recv_rtp_sink_0 \
          ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

then gstreamer reports like:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

Please help me with steps for setting up a server using gstreamer a client for performing live streaming

Answer (score 0):

Try reading manual on streaming with VLC [here](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch06.html).
Or just:

```
cvlc rtp://@:4444
```

**Update:**
Due to my bad reading skills I slightly misunderstood the question.
Here is how to set up a server:

```
gst-launch -v pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample \
    ! speexenc ! rtpspeexpay \
    ! udpsink host=224.1.1.1 port=4444 auto-multicast=true
```

or use `multiudpsink` to send to multiple clients.